Generate invite from other servers (discord.py)
I'm doing a little experiment trying to see if I can generate invite from server my bot has been added to. I encounter a problem in the definition of something called InviteTarget that I am not even using (?)
The code is the following:
    @commands.hybrid_command(name='makeinvite', with_app_command=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def makeinvite(self, ctx, channel: discord.abc.GuildChannel = None):
        """
        Generates an invitation link for any server the bot is in.
    
        Parameters:
        channel: The ID of channel you want to generate an invitation for. If not provided, it will use the current channel where command was used.
        """
        if channel is None:
            invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
        else:
            invite = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1, unique=True)

I then get the error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 827, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(self.binding, interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\cogs\admin.py", line 162, in makeinvite
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1, unique=True)
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1249, in create_invite
    if target_type is InviteTarget.unknown:
NameError: name 'InviteTarget' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\hybrid.py", line 438, in _invoke_with_namespace
    value = await self._do_call(ctx, ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'makeinvite' raised an exception: NameError: name 'InviteTarget' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\hybrid.py", line 438, in _invoke_with_namespace
    value = await self._do_call(ctx, ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\[redacted]\PycharmProjects\bot-ze-fourth\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.HybridCommandError: Hybrid command raised an error: Command 'makeinvite' raised an exception: NameError: name 'InviteTarget' is not defined


I have found several posts that either points at invite link from the current ctx.channel or with non working solutions.

Can I get the full traceback?

@Blitz I edited my post to add it :)

That's not the full traceback, there should be two tracebacks, I need the first one.

@Blitz That's actually the full traceback I get

Can't be, it should have a NameError traceback

Yeah it's NameError: name 'InviteTarget' is not defined no?

Look properly, CommandInvokeError: Command 'makeinvite' raised an exception: NameError: name 'InviteTarget' is not defined. This is not the root exception, there will be a root exception above this which will point out the line where the error occurs.

@Blitz It's because I had a cog listener for error catching, I modify my post with the full traceback ^^
